# how to get meta mask public key on javascript code

Tags: javascript, blockchain, ethereum, metamask

web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
account = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

these code bring me metamask account address. In this situation, how can i get my metamask account's public key??? (on javascript code)

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure Metamask wallet extension is installed first
2. You can get public key of loggedin account address only. ie. not someones account address.

```
if (window.ethereum) {
   try {
       const accounts = await window.ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' })
       const account = accounts[0]

       const publicKey = await window.ethereum.request({
          method: 'eth_getEncryptionPublicKey',
          params: [account],
       })
                
   } catch (error) {
       console.log({ error })
   }
}
```

Note: **accounts** is your metamask wallet address
**publicKey** is your accounts public key

Comment: According to the docs "eth_getEncryptionPublicKey" will be deprecated soon. What should we use instead?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get the full public key from the wallet, you can get only the address. There is no API for it.